# Get records exactly N days ago

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to select records that was created exactly N days ago.

I have something like this:

```
WHERE created_at = NOW() - (N || ' days')::interval
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: `select now() - '2 days'::interval` gives "2016-06-26 08:47:09.145128+02", so should work. what is the error?..

Comment: ah I see - the tipe of `created_at` probably is not `timestamp`, so you just have no data for that exac milisecond N days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the date part I believe, something like:

```
select created_at::date = (current_date - (N || ' days')::interval)::date;
```

This will take the date part of your timestamp:

```
select '2016-06-28 07:51:19.583104'::date
```

Will give you:

> 2016-06-28